# Updating multiple tables in single update statement - Exasol

Tags: sql, sql-update, exasolution

Using the below statement it gives error in Exasol however it will work in MySQL

```
update u1, u2 
set u1.name='H'
,u2.name='H'
from u1 u
inner join u2 us on (u.id=us.id);
```

Is there a way to to update multiple tables in single update query in Exasol?

Comment: Most databases -- including exasol -- only allow you to update one table at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Updating multiple table in single statement is not possible. But you may start a transaction, run individual updates and commit all changes at the end.